# Physicist needs help solving partial differencial Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

In a problem related to stochastic dynamics, I was left with the following stationary Fokker-Planck equation:
\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{N^*}\frac{\partial^2P}{\partial n_1^2} + \frac{1}{N^*}\frac{\partial^2P}{\partial n_2^2} -
    (n_1+ \alpha n_2) \frac{\partial P}{\partial n_1}-(n_2+ \alpha n_1) \frac{\partial P}{\partial n_2} - 2 P = 0
\end{equation}
where N* and $\alpha$ are constants (Real numbers). Looking at the form of the equation, I would guess there is an analytical expression for the solution. If there is a way to solve it, let me know.

Comment: can it be solved for $\alpha=0$?

Comment: Have you tried a change of variables, from $(n_1,n_2)$ to $(n_1+\alpha n_2, \alpha n_1+n_2)$?

Comment: For $\alpha = 0$ the solution is $P(n_1,n_2) = C\exp[-\frac{n_1^2+n_2^2}{2a}] $,where $a = \frac{1}{N*}$ .